# How can I create database file with Flask?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm building a website using Flask, and I'm having a problem creating the database file.
Is there a way to solve this problem without changing the structure of the project as much as possible?

Here is my project structure:

```
├── db_model

│ └── models.py

├── guide_view

│ └── guide.py

├── static

├── templates

└── app.py
```

**models.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    ...
```

**guide.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, flash, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user, logout_user
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from datetime import datetime
from db_model.models import db
from db_model.models import User

guide_view = Blueprint('guide_view', __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")

@guide_view.route('/')
@guide_view.route('/main')
def main():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_cors import CORS
from guide_view import guide
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from db_model.models import db
from db_model.models import User
import os
from os import path

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
CORS(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('FLASK_SECRET_KEY', 'guide')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///instance/database.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

def create_db(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        print("Database tables created successfully.")

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'guide_view.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)

app.register_blueprint(guide.guide_view, url_prefix="")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not path.exists('database.db'):
        create_db(app)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='1114', debug=True)
```

I check python version(3.12.0) and Flask version(3.0.0).
I also checked the terminal, but there were no logs about the database.
I'm not sure what the problem is.

If you have any other problems, please let me know.

Comment: What problem exactly?

Comment: The database file is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `models.py`, you create `db = SQLAlchemy()` connection but in your `app.py` you also create anothers. It have two db so The db create is db at app.py, not db in your model.

I suggest add a `extension.py` to store all 3rd app and you 'll import to `app.py`

Ex:

Stucture:

```
├── db_model

│ └── models.py

├── guide_view

│ └── guide.py

├── static

├── templates

└── app.py

└── extension.py
```

**extension.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**models.py**

```
from extension import db # use db from extension

class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.String(10), primary_key=True)
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_cors import CORS
from guide_view import guide
from extension import db
from db_model.models import User
import os
from os import path

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
CORS(app)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get('FLASK_SECRET_KEY', 'guide')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:///database.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

def create_db(app):
    db.init_app(app) # use db from extension
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        print("Database tables created successfully.")

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'guide_view.login'
login_manager.init_app(app)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)

app.register_blueprint(guide.guide_view, url_prefix="")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not path.exists('database.db'):
        create_db(app)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='1114', debug=True)
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested, but the database file was not created. There was no log displayed in the terminal either.

Comment: I had try in my local. It  ok. Check your permision terminal, it should have right to create new file. Also, change the env `DATABASE_URL`  in my example

Comment: I finally succeeded in creating the database file! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure you have added this in your code:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///my_db.db' 
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

In your terminal type: `python` to open the python shell.

1. `from app import app, db`
2. `db.create_all()`

Comment: I followed the method you suggested, but this error occurred : sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: Does it occur when you open the file manually? If you are, use an [sqlite-viewer](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/). If not you can [try this](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/11379)